# Feeds Module Periodic Import not working

Tags: feeds

I created a Job portal using the feeds module. I have the Periodic Import on every 3 hours. It says you have to configure your cron. I have read where there are others having issues a few years ago and they say to use Ultimate cron or Elysia Cron. I tried both and am not sure what/ where I am suppose to set and still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ultimate Cron, make sure you set the 3 hour cron to the Job Scheduler cron and and also to the Feeds crons (there are like 4 of them).